# Send xml file using httpclient in c#

Tags: xml

This method will take in as parameter an XML document, URL, and the SOAP action and make a request to a web service. HttpClient classes to make the request to the web service.

please help.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace HttpClientStatus
{
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using var client = new HttpClient();

        XmlDocument SOAPReqBody = new XmlDocument();

        SOAPReqBody.Load("C://Users//gmzmdz//Desktop//course.xml");
        var result = await client.GetAsync("http://webcode.me");
        Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Help with what?  You haven't posted any code.

Comment: @ScottHunter please check now

Comment: What question(s) do you have about it?  If it isn't working as you expect, please explain both the expectation & what it is doing instead as precisely as possible.

Comment: @ScottHunter kindly, solve my problem at new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60392652/send-xml-document-over-soap